# fop 1.1 ExternalGraphicException

Tags: java, xsl-fo, apache-fop

Good day.
I have next problem.
We used fop 1.0, but then we have upgraded to v 1.1. And now I have the problem with image displaying in rtf file.

The error looks like:

> org.apache.fop.render.rtf.rtflib.rtfdoc.RtfExternalGraphic$ExternalGraphicException
>   The tag  does not support do?message=83720404 - image type.

This is the part of my template:

```
<xsl:template match="barcodeURL">
   <xsl:variable  name="bar"  select="."/>
    <fo:external-graphic text-align="center" display-align="center" width="30mm" height="20mm" content-height="40pt" src="url('{$bar}.jpeg')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

And this is the part of java code:

```
if (isBarcodePrinting) {
    contextUrl = request.getScheme() + "://" + request.getServerName() + ":" + request.getServerPort()
            + WebContexts.common.getValue() + "/generateBarCode.do?message=";
}
```

So, I need to receive the URL another way?
Thanks.